# Tab loads internet data so is slow displaying ... How do I preprocess the loading?

Tags: android

My android app has 4 tabs. In one tab it loads twitter data from the net when I click on it. This means that the display can take up to 7 seconds to load. the function I call is getTwitterData(); how can I preprocess this step perhaps in a splash screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- for better user experience you need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to download
  dynamic data from internet
- even if you download data in splashscreen, the user will not get real time data all time

so on the tab click, use the below code segment to download data from server

```
private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(BrokerListActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Downloading...");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // download data here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void status) {
        super.onPostExecute(status);
        pd.dismiss();

        // update UI here
    }

}
```

and call use this AsyncTask in your tab click as follows

```
new DownloadData().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread` in your tab activity.